# How to make class B inherits class A with Lua?

Tags: class, inheritance, lua

What I know is to make a class like that:

```lua
A =
{
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
}

setmetatable(A, {
  __call = function(self, instance)
    return setmetatable(instance, { __index = A })
  end
})

function A:foo1()
  return string.format('Position(%d, %d)', self.x, self.y)
end

local a = A{ x = 7 } -- y will be 0 from class A
print(a.x) -- Prints 7
print(a.y) -- Prints 0
```

What I don't is to make a class B inherits this class A.
So I could make custom modifications in class B, but getting all stuffs from class A.

I'm making an event system called 'Battlefield', which would be this class A.
With this, I intent to make some mini-games like 'Bomberman' (which would be the class B that inherits class A), Pacman (which would be the class C that inherits class A), and so on.
I would like to get all stuffs from 'Battlefield' class to make both 'Bomberman' and 'Pacman' with it.
Then to make some custom modifications in 'Bomberman' that has nothing to do with 'Pacman' and vice versa.

Example:

```lua
B = -- B inherits A
{
  kills = 0,
}
-- So B class would have: x, y, kills

C = -- C inherits A
{
  deaths = 0,
}
-- So B class would have: x, y, deaths
```

[image: class B/C inherits class A]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working with my friend **Kamenuvol** about this question.

We were looking for something **readable** and **maintainable**.

Based on what we understood from the answer of **Piglet**, this was the final result:

[image: Inheritance]

```lua
function setClass(class, parentClass) -- (class[, parentClass])
  -- class.__className is required
  assert(class.__className, "Parameter '__className' is required.")

  -- Set class metatable
  setmetatable(class, {
    __index = parentClass,
    __call = function(self, instance)
      return setmetatable(instance, { __index = class })
    end
  })

  -- Attach 'is' function
  class[string.format('is%s', class.__className)] = true
end



A =
{
  __className = 'A',

  x = 0,
  y = 0,
}

setClass(A)

function A:foo1()
  return string.format('Position(%d, %d)', self.x, self.y)
end



B =
{
  __className = 'B',

  kills = 0,
}

setClass(B, A)

function B:foo2()
  return string.format('Kills(%d)', self.kills)
end



C =
{
  __className = 'C',

  deaths = 0,
}

setClass(C, A)

function C:foo3()
  return string.format('Deaths(%d)', self.deaths)
end



D =
{
  __className = 'D',

  points = 0,
}

setClass(D, C)

function D:foo4()
  return string.format('Points(%d)', self.points)
end



function A:foo5()
  return 'Hello'
end

A.foo = 'Foo'



local a = A{ x = 7 }
print(a.x) -- Prints 7
print(a.y) -- Prints 0
print(a.kills) -- Prints nil
print(a.deaths) -- Prints nil
print(a.points) -- Prints nil
print(a:foo1()) -- Prints Position(7, 0)

local b = B{ x = 8, y = 1 }
print(b.x) -- Prints 8
print(b.y) -- Prints 1
print(b.kills) -- Prints 0
print(b.deaths) -- Prints nil
print(b.points) -- Prints nil
print(b:foo1()) -- Prints Position(8, 1)
print(b:foo2()) -- Prints Kills(0)

local c = C{ x = 9, y = 2 }
print(c.x) -- Prints 9
print(c.y) -- Prints 2
print(c.kills) -- Prints nil
print(c.deaths) -- Prints 0
print(c.points) -- Prints nil
print(c:foo1()) -- Prints Position(9, 2)
print(c:foo3()) -- Prints Deaths(0)

local d = D{ x = 10, y = 3 }
print(d.x) -- Prints 10
print(d.y) -- Prints 3
print(d.kills) -- Prints nil
print(d.deaths) -- Prints 0
print(d.points) -- Prints 0
print(d:foo1()) -- Prints Position(10, 3)
print(d:foo4()) -- Prints Points(0)

print(a:foo5()) -- Prints Hello
print(b:foo5()) -- Prints Hello
print(c:foo5()) -- Prints Hello
print(d:foo5()) -- Prints Hello
print(a.foo) -- Prints Foo
print(b.foo) -- Prints Foo
print(c.foo) -- Prints Foo
print(d.foo) -- Prints Foo

print(a.isA) -- Prints true
print(a.isB) -- Prints nil
print(a.isC) -- Prints nil
print(a.isD) -- Prints nil

print(b.isA) -- Prints true
print(b.isB) -- Prints true
print(b.isC) -- Prints nil
print(b.isD) -- Prints nil

print(c.isA) -- Prints true
print(c.isB) -- Prints nil
print(c.isC) -- Prints true
print(c.isD) -- Prints nil

print(d.isA) -- Prints true
print(d.isB) -- Prints nil
print(d.isC) -- Prints true
print(d.isD) -- Prints true
```

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is implemented using `__index`.

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4

> **__index**: The indexing access operation table[key]. This event happens when table is not a table or when key is not present in table. The
> metavalue is looked up in the metatable of table. The metavalue for
> this event can be either a function, a table, or any value with an
> __index metavalue. If it is a function, it is called with table and key as arguments, and the result of the call (adjusted to one value)
> is the result of the operation. Otherwise, the final result is the
> result of indexing this metavalue with key. This indexing is regular,
> not raw, and therefore can trigger another __index metavalue.

So whenever something is not implemented in B you can refer the index operation to A.

I suggest you give this a read

http://lua-users.org/wiki/InheritanceTutorial

You can boil everything down to a function like this:

```
function CreateClass(...)
  -- "cls" is the new class
  local cls, bases = {}, {...}
  -- copy base class contents into the new class
  for i, base in ipairs(bases) do
    for k, v in pairs(base) do
      cls[k] = v
    end
  end
  -- set the class's __index, and start filling an "is_a" table that contains this class and all of its bases
  -- so you can do an "instance of" check using my_instance.is_a[MyClass]
  cls.__index, cls.is_a = cls, {[cls] = true}
  for i, base in ipairs(bases) do
    for c in pairs(base.is_a) do
      cls.is_a[c] = true
    end
    cls.is_a[base] = true
  end
  -- the class's __call metamethod
  setmetatable(cls, {__call = function (c, ...)
    local instance = setmetatable({}, c)
    -- run the init method if it's there
    local init = instance._init
    if init then init(instance, ...) end
    return instance
  end})
  -- return the new class table, that's ready to fill with methods
  return cls
end
```

If you understand this snippet you should know everything necessary.

Comment: Hello. I was working with my friend Kamenuvol about this question, so I will post what was the result. Thanks for your answer and time!